# rake aborted! wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Running rake routes gives out a "wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)" error. Also running rake without any task throws same result. Here is the output for both (rake --trace):

Note: this happens even with an empty routes.rb
rake version is (10.4.2)

** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke test:run (first_time)
** Execute test:run
rake aborted!
wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:90:in `initialize'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:90:in`new'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:90:in `action_methods'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:548:in`respond_to?'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:99:in `block in <module:UrlFor>'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in`class_eval'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `append_features'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:117:in`include'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:117:in `block in append_features'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:117:in`each'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:117:in `append_features'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb:33:in`include'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in`instance_eval'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in`block in run_load_hooks'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`run_load_hooks'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:945:in `<class:Base>'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:417:in`'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb:59:in`block in '
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in`execute_hook'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`each'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in`block in '
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/tsort.rb:150:in`block in tsort_each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/tsort.rb:219:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/tsort.rb:180:in`each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/tsort.rb:148:in`tsort_each'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in`initialize!'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/test/test_helper.rb:2:in`require'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/test/controllers/links_controller_test.rb:1:in`require'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/test/controllers/links_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in`require'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in`each'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in`each'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:205:in`call'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:200:in`each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:158:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:151:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in`invoke_rake_task'
/home4/libreame/rails_apps/websquid/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:205:in`call'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:200:in`each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:158:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:151:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:174:in`each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:157:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:151:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/application.rb:116:in`invoke_task'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/application.rb:94:in`each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/application.rb:133:in`standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/application.rb:66:in`block in run'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rake/application.rb:63:in`run'
/usr/bin/rake:32:in `'
Tasks: TOP => test:run

Gemfile so far:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
#gem 'execjs'
#gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'libv8', '3.11.8.3'
gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.0beta5'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem 'mysql2', '0.3.13'

gem 'thin'

gem 'open_uri_redirections'

gem 'certified'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the gemfile solved this. Before:

```
#gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'libv8', '3.11.8.3'
gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.0beta5'
```

Instead, I wrote:

```
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
#gem 'libv8', '3.11.8.3'
#gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.0beta5'
```

It was related to a Javascript runtime, but rake error was way too cryptic.